# Handling an HttpRequest's body in Dart

Tags: dart

I used to do something like this:

```dart
HttpResponse res = req.response;
    String dataReceived;

    await req.listen((List<int> buffer) {
      dataReceived = new String.fromCharCodes(buffer);
    }).asFuture();

    Map data = JSON.decode(dataReceived);
```

When I needed UTF8 support, I modified it to:

```dart
Map data = JSON.decode(await new Utf8Codec().decodeStream(request));
```

Kevin Moore suggested to encode/decode like this:

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/1d229cfdc1c1fd2ab877

So I've got:

```dart
Map data;
  await request.listen((List<int> buffer) {
    data = JSON.fuse(UTF8).decode(buffer);
  }).asFuture();
```

Not sure that I need the `asFuture()`:

```dart
Map data;
await request.listen((List<int> buffer) => data = JSON.fuse(UTF8).decode(buffer));
```

Or do I? And this method requires that I encode it into bytes on the client side:

```dart
sendData: new JsonUtf8Encoder().convert({'model': message, 'authToken': app.authToken}))
```

What are the benefits of this? Isn't it more to send over the wire?

I believe Shelf and/or the new RPC lib would handle this stuff for me? Shall I move to one of those? Right now, it's all homegrown.

Answer (score 4):

`HttpRequest` is a `Stream<List<int>>`. You don't want to use `listen` because you'll only get the first "chunk" of data.

Instead you'll want to do something like this:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

main() async {
  var input = {'a':1, 'b':2};

  var decoder = JSON.fuse(UTF8).decoder;

  var json = await decoder.bind(toByteStream(input)).single;

  print(json);
}

Stream<List<int>> toByteStream(json) =>
   _encoder.bind(new Stream.fromIterable([json]));


final _encoder = new JsonUtf8Encoder();
```

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/9807d0c5ed89360c9f53

Comment: Having trouble correlating your `input` to what comes in via the `HttpRequest`. I used to send JSON over the wire, and now I must do encode it client-side? `new JsonUtf8Encoder().convert(myJson);`? And if so, isn't that heavier to send over the wire?

Answer (score 3):

Yes as you can see on https://github.com/dart-lang/shelf/blob/master/lib/src/message.dart#L136 shelf defaults to UTF-8

I am likely biased but I would definitely recommend moving over to shelf. You have several options depending on what you prefer, like:

- shelf_rpc as you mentioned. I haven't used it but likely full featured API support
- shelf_bind if you simply want to bind a handler function parameter to a JSON body. This is lower level, more flexible and less prescriptive but does less. e.g.

  router.post('/foo', (@RequestBody() Foo foo) => ...)
- shelf_rest. Adds higher level more prescriptive API support (similar to shelf_rpc).
- full frameworks like redstone, mojito etc. These do more for you but you need to buy into more

Comment: I'm exploring `shelf` w/ the `rpc` package, which seems to make use of `shelf_rpc`. See https://github.com/dart-lang/rpc/blob/master/example/shelf_sample.dart. Make sense? In a refactor, I think I'd like to make my whole server-side an RPC API.

Answer (score 1):

Had a chat w/ Kevin to better understand his answer, and thought it best to share my learnings as a new answer.

`HttpRequest` is always a `Stream<List<int>>` – a streamed list of integers. Those integers are bytecodes, and this is commonly referred to as a bytestream. You can be sure that no matter what API you use to send data over the wire, that it is sent as a bytestream.

The `HttpRequest.request()` method accepts `sendData` in several forms...

```
   * If specified, `sendData` will send data in the form of a [ByteBuffer],
   * [Blob], [Document], [String], or [FormData] along with the HttpRequest.
```

Source:
https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.HttpRequest#id_request

...but these are just abstractions, and ultimately your data is sent as a `Stream<List<int>>` bytestream.

So on the server we first set up a `decoder` that will decode both JSON and UTF8 (for correct char handling), and then we `bind` that to the `HttpRequest` request, which is a bytestream. I think `single` just serves to ensure we throw an exception if we received more than one data event. Here's all the code we need to interpret an `HttpRequest`:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

static handleRequest(HttpRequest request) async {
  var decoder = JSON.fuse(UTF8).decoder;
  var data = await decoder.bind(request).single;

  print('The decoded data received is:\n\n$data');
}
```